# Что нужно сделать, чтобы при изменения размера, страница была по середине?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при изменение размера странице, все содержимое было привязано к центру, а не расходилось по бокам?

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  height: 669px;
}

a {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #222222;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
}

#now {
  color: #00CCC7;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="heading" style=" margin: 0 auto;">
    <img src="../Images/someLogo.png" alt="logo">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="now">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project single</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Если в `body` изменять параметр `width`, то все нормально, но если его поставить на `100%`, то все притягивается по краям, а единое значение я не могу задать, так как у всех экраны разные.

Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width:100%;
  padding:0 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно задать максимальную ширину включая внутренние отступы и вам не нужно будет добавлять медиа запросы

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно завести класс `.container` к которому вы привяжите ширину для определенных устройств при помощи `@media`, пример как это выглядит:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Далее для различных экранов, например, для desktop разрешения (`1280px`) вы можете задать ширину Вашего контейнера в `1170px`(к примеру), для планшетов(`712px`), так же, к примеру, Вы можете задать разрешение контейнера `460px`

> P.S. Все числа брались "наобум", вместо того, чтобы пытаться
>   настраивать правила `@media` для конкретных устройств, возможно, более
>   целесообразно использовать их на Вашем конкретном макете. То есть,
>   постепенно сокращайте окно рабочего стола браузера и наблюдайте
>   естественные точки `(breakpoints)` для Вашего контента. Они отличаются
>   для каждого сайта.